# scalatest - can't expand macros compiled by previous versions of Scala

Tags: scala, maven, scalatest

So we have a Scala program (built using Maven) we want to test using Scalatest. We're running Scala 2.11.8 and Scalatest 3.0.1 (we've tried 3.0.3 to no avail)

When our tests run anything with the `assert()` macro, we get the following error:

```
error: can't expand macros compiled by previous versions of Scala
       assert(true)
              ^
```

It points to the `true` but the issue is with anything we put into `assert()`. Our POM has the following dependency for Scalatest:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
    <artifactId>scalatest_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

The code we're trying to execute is:

```
import org.scalatest.{FlatSpec, _}
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.scalatest.junit.JUnitRunner


@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
class Testing extends FlatSpec {
  //test
  var number = 0;
  "An empty Set" should "have size 0" in {
    assert(true)

  }
}
```

Lot's of folks say this is an issue with using Scala 2.11 but including the 2.10 dependency, but we're using the 2.11 one. Any help would be much appreciated. I should also note we tried it using Scala 2.10, and it worked.

Comment: The message definitely says _something_ compiled for wrong Scala version is involved. You may want to include the complete POM. Note that having explicit `_2.11` instead of using a property is an antipattern which makes it quite likely to leave a `_2.10` or `_2.12` by accident when switching between Scala versions.

Comment: Yeah it was actually using a property that I filled in so you guys knew what it was. I'm going to try out the below answer and see if another dependency is using it. Unfortunately, I left my work computer at work for the weekend. There are no references to 2.10 but maybe there is a 2.12 in the POM 

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Run `mvn dependency:tree` and find out which dependencies have _2.10 in it. 
Use [Dependency management](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Management) to ensure the _2.11 is included, and _2.10
is excluded.

Comment: This absolutely helped me figure it out. Turns out one of our dependencies was including a 2.10 jar, which included scalatest_2.10. Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad it helped.